# ListView issue with Angular2 final

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

We use NativeScript 2.3 with Angular2 final.
We have an issue with the ListView component. We can bind something to the view but it always display this:
[image]

Here's the code of the template:
`

```
<GridLayout row="0" columns="*, auto" class="add-bar">
    <!--<TextField #groceryTextField [(ngModel)]="grocery" hint="Enter a grocery item" col="0"></TextField>-->
    <!--<Image src="res://add" (tap)="add()" col="1"></Image>-->
</GridLayout>

<ListView [items]="orderForms" row="1" class="small-spacing" [class.visible]="listLoaded">
    <template let-item="item">
        <GridLayout columns="*, auto">
            <Label col="0" [text]="item.frameworkContractNumber" class="medium-spacing"></Label>
            <Label col="1" [text]="item.requestIdentifier" class="medium-spacing"></Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </template>
 </ListView>
```

With the previous RC of angular it was working. Now whatever we try(array, observables, ...) we end up with this. It's the same on Android and IOS.

Any ideas?

Comment: I create a HelloWorld app recently with a ListView. You can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50259599/3332734

Comment: You must need to use `ng-template` instead `template`