# NativeScript - Filter a ListView data by tabs from TabView-ng

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

How can I show up by demand only data related by specific room?

Below my Json data:

```
{
  "rooms": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Room 01",
      "content": "Content 01"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Room 02",
      "content": "Room 02"
    }
  ],
  "tables": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "number": 1,
      "roomId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "number": 2,
      "roomId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "number": 3,
      "roomId": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

My template:

```
<TabView [(ngModel)]="tabSelectedIndex" selectedColor="#FF0000">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let tab of roomsList">
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: tab.name}">
      <ListView [items]="tablesList">
        <ng-template let-item="item">
          <Label [text]="item.number"></Label>
        </ng-template>
      </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
  </ng-container>
</TabView>
```

My class Component using Angular core and my personal `FileReader` class to read and return a JSON data. See it below:

```
export class DataItem {
  constructor(public name: string, public content: string) {}
}

export class TableItem {
  constructor(public number: number) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  // Your TypeScript logic goes here
  public roomsList: Array<DataItem>;
  public tabSelectedIndex: number;
  public tablesList: Array<TableItem>;

  private loadRooms(roomsList: Array<DataItem>) {
    this.tabSelectedIndex = (!!roomsList.length) ? 1 : 0;
    this.roomsList = roomsList.map(item => new DataItem(item.name, item.content));
  }

  private loadTables(tablesList: Array<TableItem>) {
    this.tablesList = tablesList.map(item => new TableItem(item.number));
  }

  private loadInterface() {
    FileReader
      .readJSON('./config/interface.json')
      .then((output: Array<object>) => {
        const roomsList = output['rooms'];
        const tablesList = output['tables'];

        this.loadRooms(roomsList);
        this.loadTables(tablesList);
      });
  }

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadInterface();
  }
}
```

References:

- [NativeScript - TabView-ng](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/cookbook/tab-view-ng)
- [Dynamic tabs in TabView-ng NativeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47310765/3332734)
- [Filter ListView using angular2 in NativeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114402/filter-listview-using-angular2-in-nativescript#41150752)

Answer (score 0):

I recent solved that creating a new array [] and increment using `map()` + `filter()` + `push()` the filtered into the new array.

```
private filteredRooms(roomsList, tablesList) {
    const filteredRooms = [];

    roomsList.map(room => {
      const filteredTables = tablesList.filter((t: TableItem) => t.roomId === room.id);
      const filteredRoom = room;

      filteredRoom['tables'] = filteredTables;

      filteredRooms.push(filteredRoom);
    });

    return filteredRooms;
    }
```

And change the `tablesList` to `tables` on ListView.